# CREATE command denied to user in Knime database writer node

Tags: mysql, database, knime

In a new KNIME workflow. I created a new database connection node and a new Database Writer node that accepts its data from a CSV reader node.
The execution of the database connection node is successful.
When I execute the Database writer node, I am getting a CREATE command is denied error.

The configurations of the Database connector node are as follows:
Database URL : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello_knime_database 
 Username : test 
 Password : test

mysql configurations:

```
$ mysql -u test -p
mysql> show databases;
+----------------------+
| Database             |
+----------------------+
| information_schema   |
| hello_knime_database |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------+
| Grants for test@localhost                                                                    
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost'                                                    
|
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hello_knime_database`.* TO 'test'@'localhost'                      
|
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hello_knime_database`.`hello_knime_database` TO 
'test'@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Database Writer configurations: 
Port 1 input: data table of around 32000 rows and 15 columns. 
Port 2 input: the database connector 
Table name: hello

KNIME version : 3.3.2

When I execute the Database Writer node I get:

```
ERROR Database Writer      0:3        Execute failed: CREATE command denied to user 'test'@'localhost' for table 'hello'
```

Any clues of what is causing this?

Comment: Adding a fully qualified table name by appending the database name as a prefix such as : `hello_knime_database.hello` has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySql

> A grant table reload affects privileges for each existing client
>   connection as follows:
>       Table and column privilege changes take effect with the client's next request.
>       Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client executes a USE db_name statement.
>
> ```
> Note
> Client applications may cache the database name; thus, this effect may not be visible to them without actually changing to a different  database or flushing the privileges.
> ```
>
> Global privileges and passwords are unaffected for a connected client.
>   These changes take effect only for subsequent connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `The Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client executes a USE db_name statement`. I do not know what is the direct way to do that in KNIME. What i did is creating a Database Reader and configure it by setting the query to `USE hello_knime_database` and that did the trick !

Comment: I am very impressed by your smart way to find the answer in the MySQL documentation. Can you help us with some tips on how did you search for the answer and what keywords did you use? Best Regards,

Comment: @mtleis Happy  to hear that your problem solved. :-) . I came across this situation before, I already know the issue. Thank you